# How do I map a Time field using Glass.Mapper?

Tags: glass-mapper

I've got a field in my template of type Time, the template is published and I've entered a value in my item but I'm not getting a value in my datasource.

I've tried `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` for the property type but all I get is `default(T)`

```
public virtual DateTime TimeOfDay {get;set;}

public virtual TimeSpan TimeOfDay {get;set;}
```

I've published the item and the template.

If I get the raw item via `Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(...)` I can see the field has a value, so it's entered and published properly, just not mapping.  I've Googled but can't see anything relating to the Time field type.

What am I missing? How do I get the value to map to the glass model?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a `Time` field type. Is it a custom implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a custom field. You can check this by going to `core:/sitecore/system/Field types` and looking at the field in question. It will most likely have a namespace that is part of your codebase in the assembly and class fields. 
What you need is a glass custom field mapper, this blog post explains it quite well...

https://sitecorecorner.com/2014/10/02/glass-mapper-and-custom-time-field/